# bash transfer multiple files in seq and uniq to sub folders

Tags: shell-script, bash-array

I have thousands or more than thousands of files like

```
A20200727.2015+0200-2030+0200_SubNetwork=ppp,MeContext=xxx23,celltracefile_DUL1_3.bin.gz
A20200727.2015+0200-2030+0200_SubNetwork=ppp,MeContext=ggg13,celltracefile_DUL1_3.bin.gz
A20200727.2015+0200-2030+0200_SubNetwork=ppp,MeContext=aaa56,celltracefile_DUL1_3.bin.gz
A20200727.2015+0200-2030+0200_SubNetwork=ppp,MeContext=slsf86,celltracefile_DUL1_3.bin.gz
A20200727.2015+0200-2030+0200_SubNetwork=ppp,MeContext=ccc57,celltracefile_DUL1_3.bin.gz
```

I am trying to `cut`-`sort`-`uniq` `xxx23`, `ggg13`, `aaa56`, `slsf86` characters, there are thousands of them. Calculate how many of them, transfer to subfolders as bunch of 800 of uniq `xxx23`, `ggg13`, `aaa56`, `slsf86`, Transfer them from source to multiple folders of 800 uniq of them in counts.

My idea, to put the list into array and call array values to each subfolder
how can I make this every growing as subsequent folders to automatically created as further number 800 goes

```
#!/bin/bash

origFolder="/data/rawdata/temp"
destFolder="/data/rawdata/cpp_tr"
NoOfFilesinEachDir=800

###################################################################################################

numberTR=`ls $origFolder | egrep "^A[[:digit:]]{8}\.[[:digit:]]{4}.*bin.gz" | cut -f2 -d',' | cut -d'=' -f2 | sort | uniq | wc -l`
siteuniq=`ls $origFolder | egrep "^A[[:digit:]]{8}\.[[:digit:]]{4}.*bin.gz" | cut -f2 -d',' | cut -d'=' -f2 | sort | uniq`


##Calculate and create folders required to put 800files.
for count in $NoOfFilesinEachDir; do
    nn=1
    numberofbunch=$((numberTR%count?numberTR/count+1:numberTR/count))
    if [[ $numberTR -le $count ]]; then
        mkdir "$destFolder/cpptr_$nn"
    else [[ $numberTR -gt $count ]];
        for (( pp=1; pp<=$numberofbunch; pp++ )); do
            mkdir "$destFolder/cpptr_$pp"
        done
    fi
done


## I am trying to make this list automate for no of folders created above
for number in $NoOfFilesinEachDir; do
kkk=()
#echo $site
read -r -a kkk <<< $siteuniq
lastelement=$(echo "${#siteuniq[@]}")
    for (( bb=0; bb<=$number; bb++ )); do
        find $origFolder -regextype sed -regex ".*${kkk[bb]}*.*" -exec  cp -fp {} $destFolder/cpptr_1 \;
    done
    
    for (( cc=801; cc<=1600; cc++ )); do
        find $origFolder -regextype sed -regex ".*${kkk[cc]}*.*" -exec  cp -fp {} $destFolder/cpptr_2 \;
    done
    
    for (( dd=1601; dd<=2400; dd++ )); do
        find $origFolder -regextype sed -regex ".*${kkk[dd]}*.*" -exec  cp -fp {} $destFolder/cpptr_3 \;
    done
    for (( dd=2401; dd<=$lastelement; dd++ )); do
        find $origFolder -regextype sed -regex ".*${kkk[dd]}*.*" -exec  cp -fp {} $destFolder/cpptr_4 \;
    done
done
~
```

Comment: What do you mean by "transfer to subfolders as bunch of 800 of uniq xxx23, ggg13, aaa56, slsf86"? Do you want 800 files in each folder and no repetition of any of the `MeContext=` values? Are all your filenames identical apart from the string after `MeContext=`?

Comment: Could you add the expected output/results based on that example input so that we know exactly what you want to achieve ? If I understand your problem correctly, the following should do it: `ls | perl -ne 'chomp;/\S+Context\=(\S+),\S+/;system "mkdir $1 ; mv $_ $1";'`

Comment: @terdon -No its not identical, there are multiple dates and time. Its more than 500 thousand files per day.

name of node after ex - like this one MeContext=xxx212 and others all unique, each of xxx212 have 24 hour and have different time stamps for whole day. For ex - this is for one of them 

A20200727.1615+0200-1630+0200_SubNetwork=ppp,MeContext=xxx212,celltracefile_DUL1_1.bin.gz
A20200727.1615+0200-1630+0200_SubNetwork=ppp,MeContext=xxx212,celltracefile_DUL1_3.bin.gz
A20200727.1630+0200-1645+0200_SubNetwork=ppp,MeContext=xxx212,celltracefile_DUL1_1.bin.gz

Comment: have you tought about incrontab job instant doing the desired changes immediately?